# Make a new column for each category in a particular column and repeat this for all columns in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like below-:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'state':['California'] * 4 + ['Florida'] * 5 + ['Minnesota'] * 3 + ['New Hampshire'],
'population':['50-100', '0-50', '150-200', '50-100', '0-50', '150-200',
         '100-150', 'NA', '0-50', 'NA', '100-150', '50-100', 'NA'],
'locale':['rural', 'urban', 'town', 'suburb', 'suburb', 'urban', 'rural', 'suburb', 'NA', 'town', 'town', 'urban', 'rural'] 
})
```

I want new columns for each category in all columns for each state. An example of a row is below-:

```
state        population=0-50 population=50-100 population=100-150 population=150-200 locale=rural locale=urban locale=town locale=suburb
California   1               2                 0                  1                  1          1              1            1
```

**EDIT**
Data dump of 1st 5 rows as asked-:

```
{'state': {0: 'Connecticut',
  1: 'Connecticut',
  2: 'Connecticut',
  3: 'Connecticut',
  4: 'Connecticut'},
 'locale': {0: 'Suburb', 1: 'Suburb', 2: 'Suburb', 3: 'Suburb', 4: 
'Suburb'},
 'pct_black/hispanic': {0: '[0.6, 0.8[',
  1: '[0.6, 0.8[',
  2: '[0.6, 0.8[',
  3: '[0.6, 0.8[',
  4: '[0.6, 0.8['},
 'pct_free/reduced': {0: '[0.2, 0.4[',
  1: '[0.2, 0.4[',
  2: '[0.2, 0.4[',
  3: '[0.2, 0.4[',
  4: '[0.2, 0.4['},
 'county_connections_ratio': {0: '[0.18, 1[',
  1: '[0.18, 1[',
  2: '[0.18, 1[',
  3: '[0.18, 1[',
  4: '[0.18, 1['},
 'pp_total_raw': {0: 'NA', 1: 'NA', 2: 'NA', 3: 'NA', 4: 'NA'}}
```

Comment: Any further clarification of the answer required ?

Comment: I am still trying the solution. Will give you feedback in a short while.

Comment: As your real data seen from the data dump of real data actually differ considerably from the sample data of your initial version of question, I would suggest you create a new question on the real layout.  Remember to also create the sample data with different values for different rows and also show the desired output based on this minimal set (but adequate to cover all data scenarios) of data.

Comment: I removed the .head() part from your solution and it worked.

Comment: Great that my solution finally worked for you.  But I'm puzzle where's the .head() part ?  My solution doesn't have the 'head()` in it, right ?!   Anyway, please accept my solution and upvote it.  It is important you upvote it also since it has a negative vote by someone previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) + [`Groupby.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), as follows:

```
(pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('state'))
   .groupby('state').sum()
   .reset_index()
)
```

**Result:**

```
           state  population_0-50  population_100-150  population_150-200  population_50-100  population_NA  locale_NA  locale_rural  locale_suburb  locale_town  locale_urban
0     California                1                   0                   1                  2              0          0             1              1            1             1
1        Florida                2                   1                   1                  0              1          1             1              2            0             1
2      Minnesota                0                   1                   0                  1              1          0             0              0            2             1
3  New Hampshire                0                   0                   0                  0              1          0             1              0            0             0
```

If you want to exclude the entries with value `NA`, you can use:

```
(pd.get_dummies(df[df != 'NA'].set_index('state'))
   .groupby('state').sum()
   .reset_index()
)
```

**Result:**

```
           state  population_0-50  population_100-150  population_150-200  population_50-100  locale_rural  locale_suburb  locale_town  locale_urban
0     California                1                   0                   1                  2             1              1            1             1
1        Florida                2                   1                   1                  0             1              2            0             1
2      Minnesota                0                   1                   0                  1             0              0            2             1
3  New Hampshire                0                   0                   0                  0             1              0            0             0
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but I am only getting one row and limited columns.

Comment: @ManuVats  How is your real data different from the sample data you provided here ?  To further investigate, please provide a data dump of the first 5 rows of your data by `df.head(5).to_dict()`.  Please post the dump as an edit at the end of your question.

Comment: I've added the dump of actual data.

Comment: @ManuVats  I'll take a look.  However, your real data seems differ a lot from the sample data at the initial question.  Real data has repeating values (at least for the first 5 rows) instead of different values in the `Population` column in sample.

Comment: Ok! I can provide the complete dataset if you want.

Comment: @ManuVats  See my comment in your question. I'm deleting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution given by @SeaBean worked.

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('state')).groupby('state').sum().reset_index()
```